# Bluetooth audio device reports wrong class, how to override it?

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I **can** connect to and use my HiFi system via BT just fine but... it is listed as 'Headset' in my audio device list. A totally minor issue but a bit confusing.

I found out that the (probable...) reason behind this 'misunderstanding' is that the device reports its class as 0x240404 (*Wearable headset device*) instead of the likely more appropriate 0x240428 (*HiFi Audio Device*).

Unfortunately simply editing the `/var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC address]/[another MAC address]/info` file doesn't work, as the file gets rewritten at each service restart and the reported class gets back everytime.

How can I override the reported class for the device? (It can't be changed from the HiFi device itself, at least according to the manual there's no BT 'advanced options' where I could operate...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find a better solution, I just hacked the bluetooth daemon code. In case someone else needs it - or something similar, I added one line into bluez src/device.c *device_set_class* function. It's a terrible solution (any headset device will be miscategorized as HiFi) but it serves my purpose.

```
void device_set_class(struct btd_device *device, uint32_t class)
{
    if (device->class == class)
        return;

    DBG("%s 0x%06X", device->path, class);

  if ((class & 0xffffff)==0x240404)   class=0x240428;    // BT speaker fix!

    device->class = class;

    store_device_info(device);

    g_dbus_emit_property_changed(dbus_conn, device->path,
                        DEVICE_INTERFACE, "Class");
    g_dbus_emit_property_changed(dbus_conn, device->path,
                        DEVICE_INTERFACE, "Icon");
}
```

though I suspect there should be a better way. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're using Gnome as your desktop environment. Similar options might exist or not exist in other environments.

I solved the problem described by you on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS several weeks ago and did not yet upgrade to 22.04.1 LTs - but checked the changelogs.

It is more than probable that your *HiFi Audio Device* supports more than one Bluetooth profile - so do most of the recent BT headsets.

A general word about two-way Bluetooth-Connections: There is no "non-proprietary generig" way (or at least I don't know any), to have a two-way HighQuality audio connection via Bluetooth. Device Manufacturers might supply proprietary, device-specific software to accomplish this. In most cases this software would not be compiled for Linux.

One possible workaround could be a Bluetooth USB dongle being recognized as a (two-way) sound card by your Computer. But this is beyound your original question.

### using your HiFi Audio device to play sounds coming from your computer

Once you have connected your HiFi Audio device via Bluetooth, go to `gnome-control-center sound` (either by klicking through "settings" or by running that command after pressing F2 or Ctrl+Alt+T (3 at the same time)).

First scroll down to "Input" and set it to something else but not your HiFi Audio device connected via Bluetooth - or mute it. Either will work.

Second go up to "Output" and choose your OutputDevice (obvious) and the Bluetooth profile of your choice beside *Configuration* (A2DP Sink with one of the supplied Codecs)

On Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS I had to do an additional step *before* this became possible:

- install the package `pulseaudio-modules-bt` from [https://launchpad.net/~berglh/+archive/ubuntu/pulseaudio-a2dp](https://launchpad.net/%7Eberglh/+archive/ubuntu/pulseaudio-a2dp)  - it will ask you to uninstall the package `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` because it will replace the latter (in a package-manager-compliant way).

Unfortunately the above-mentioned package's "activity" looks like a one-time shot packaging https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The version of `pulseaudio` found on Ubuntu 22.04 should be able to support this "out of the box" - according to the changelogs I read (did not test with a live ubuntu 22.04.1). If not - find a suitable ppa for 22.04  of `pulseaudio-modules-bt` - chances are high.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I *do* get audio from the HiFi, it's just that it's reported as headset. There's only one output profile when I select the device and it's "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" which seems correct btw...